# Generating unique slugs from titles

Tags: database, web, slug

What's the best way to deal with slugs when it comes to repetition. Let's say for example the slug is for a blog post. It seems standard slug conversion seems to remove all non alphanumeric characters and then lower the case and lastly breaks spaces with either an under score or a hyphen. But there's issues, for example:

Titles => Slug

1. Top 500 Sport Activities    => top-500-sports-activities
2. Top $500 Sports Activities  => top-500-sports-activities

There's a slug duplication to two unique titles. Is there a method to getting around this? Perhaps simple safe symbol conversions?

However, I would like it to be able to same slug from each title given as a way to prevent duplication of post items.

Comment: Yep, I think you've summed up how Wordpress's sanitize_title_with_dashes() works. Some CMS allow duplicate titles (e.g. "New Post") and handle the slugs as new-post-1, new-post-2, and so on. What you could do is write the slugs manually yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for is a unique ID but I don't like the Wordpress system. The project I'm working on is dependent on the style of the slug. Is it safe to use characters like $ ; @ ? ! In a Restful slug, or will the browser break them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot obtain unique slugs in general because of the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). You are mapping from a bigger set into a smaller one which implies duplicates.

You can, of course, do tricks with symbols and try to insert underscores of dashes are already taken. That is not a general solution, though, because not all symbols can be used (there wouldn't be a need for a slug). You probably need to resort to adding another token to the URL like a date or a sequence number.

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to go with a "top-500-sports-activities" and then check if it exists and if not attempt with the wordpress style "-number": top-500-sports-activities-1, top-500-sports-activities-2. But thanks for pointing me to the Pigeonhole Principle, that was a pretty cool read.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding year/month/day to your URLs to support non-unique slugs. Also remember to add a date field to  your unique constraint.